How use CFSSL for create certificate?
How create code sing cert use CFSSL
I want to create .crt/.cert and .pfx/p12 files to sign application code
There is also an additional question if I create a certificate and put it in the trusted root certificate store for signing I can sign my code with it and not use testsign?
I check READ-ME but i dont understand how create cert
